# How to fix 'JavaScript heap out of memory' error in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, nuxt.js, heap-memory

I have used nuxt 3 in one of my project and I have configured the `generate_staging` script to generate a staging build as below

```js
"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate --max-old-space-size=8096",
    "generate_staging": "NUXT_MODE=staging nuxt generate --max-old-space-size=80096",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
```

Now when I run `npm run generate_staging` it returns a `JavaScript heap out of memory` error.

I have already set the `--max-old-space-size=80096`

Kindly please help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Update your script like this and try, `"generate": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 nuxt generate` It worked for me